# Are JPMS modifiers `static` and `transitive` incompatible?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, bnd

The JPMS `requires` instruction can have two qualifiers `static` and `transitive`. For a module `foo`:

- `requires static bar;`, makes resolution of the `bar` module optional at runtime,
- `requires transitive bar;`, allows each module that reads `foo` to also read `bar`. According to the [`java.lang.module` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/package-summary.html) this also means that `bar` must be present at both compiletime and runtime.

There is however a third option allowed:

```java
module foo {
    requires static transitive bar;
}
```

What is this combination supposed to do?

According to the Javadoc:

> `requires` directives that have the `static` modifier express an optional dependence at run time. If a module declares that it `requires static M` then resolution does not search the observable modules for M to satisfy the dependency. However, if M is recursively enumerated at step 1 then all modules that are enumerated and `requires static M` will read M.

where "step 1" describes the computation of the closure of the set of root modules by the `X requires transitive Y` relation.

If I interpret this correctly, if a `requires` directive is both `static` and `transitive`, the `foo` module is **not optional**, since "step 1" requires its presence.

We often end up with such directives, when using the [`bnd-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/maven-plugins/bnd-maven-plugin), which maps the OSGi `resolution:=optional` directive to `static` and the `uses:=...` directive to `transitive`.